# How can I expose my Web API endpoint to other resource applications in Azure AD?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, single-sign-on, azure-ad-graph-api

I was following the guide [active-directory-integrating-applications](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/active-directory/active-directory-integrating-applications.md#configuring-a-resource-application-to-expose-web-apis) I downloaded the app manifest and it already had the equivalent oauth2Persission:

```
"oauth2Permissions": [
{
  "adminConsentDescription": "Allow the application to access ShippingScheduleAPI on behalf of the signed-in user.",
  "adminConsentDisplayName": "Access ShippingScheduleAPI",
  "id": "ba650239-2de4-41c1-979b-886a9427389a",
  "isEnabled": true,
  "type": "User",
  "userConsentDescription": "Allow the application to access ShippingScheduleAPI on your behalf.",
  "userConsentDisplayName": "Access ShippingScheduleAPI",
  "value": "user_impersonation"
}
```

],

However when I go to my client application and try to add the application it does not show up under "All Apps".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the drop down to show "All Apps" does not change the filter till you select the check box

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, but with the new version of Azure Portal.

All my custom apis would not show by default. In order to be able to select one of them (to give permissions), I needed to type the name of the app in the filter box then press enter. The api would show up after that.